# MSB3258: mscorlib 4.0.0.0 and 2.0.0.0

Tags: c#, dll, visual-studio-2017, mscorlib

So I'm trying to compile a project on VS 2017, and I'm getting this:

```
 warning MSB3258: The primary reference "someLib.dll" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the .NET Framework assembly "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" which has a higher version "4.0.0.0" than the version "2.0.0.0" in the current target framework.
```

After that, I have errors relating to this dll (for example, a type or namespace not being in the namespace), but when I double click the error it disappears, along with the red squiggly line in the code, hinting at the fact that it's not the actual problem.

Nothing I tried is working: all of the projects are on 3.5, I removed and re-added all of my references, and it doesn't happen in any other computer except my own.  I also tried removing mscorlib from the GAC (however dumb that may be), but of course it won't let me.

I saw something that may be relevant:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/230636/assemblydependency-now-misidentifying-indirect-dep.html

Other than removing and reinstalling VS, not sure what to do.
If anyone has any idea, I'd be glad to try it.

Comment: What libraries are referenced in the `someLib.dll`?

Comment: Other than some libraries in my project, these guys:
BouncyCastle.Crypto
log4net
Microsoft.Web.Administration
Shell32
System
System.configuration
System.Core
System.Data
System.Data.DataSetExtensions
System.ServiceProcess
System.Xml
System.Xml.Linq

Comment: To me the error tells you, that some libraries of the above has a reference to `mscorlib 4.0.0.0`. Did you checked the referenced libraries of `BouncyCastle.Crypto` and `log4net`? I assume the MS libraries are fine.

Comment: It's not BouncyCastle. I'm checking log4net now.

Comment: It's not lof4net either, they support all versions pretty much.
I've been removing references all day, and don't know if it's productive.

Comment: How did you added the Microsoft libraries to the project? Via Add Reference > "Assemblies tab" or by browsing for them? Did you readded the MS libraries as well?

Comment: It's Interop.Shell32.dll. Worked all day for that.
Now to understand why. I need to use this.

Comment: Frustrating... I think every developer knows that fights. Glad you got it now. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a weird reference to a version of Interop.Shell32.dll called just "Shell32.dll". Don't know where it came from.

If anyone else has this issue: remove each dependency one at a time and compile. Even the Microsoft ones.

Answer (score 0):

Answer from comments:

Check the libraries `someLib.dll` references. Maybe they contain a reference to `mscorlib.dll 4.0.0.0`.

Hint: add official Microsoft libraries via  Via Add Reference > "Assemblies tab" (on the left, don't know if tab is correctly named). Don't add them by browsing for them.